# Changing webView content in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, html, web

I want to take a pages source code, find specific text and replace it with different text. Then I want to display the altered page to the user. Is there a way to do this in Android Studio?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags), and [the tagging guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 3):

Something you could do is use a custom WebView and add a new method to load a URL's  HTML yourself and modify the returned HMTL. Here's a Kotlin example using coroutines:

```
class OverrideWebView : WebView {
    constructor(context: Context?) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs)
    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)

    private val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient()

    fun loadUrlAndReplace(url: String, replace: (String) -> String) {
        val request = Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build()

        GlobalScope.launch {
            okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute().body()?.string()?.let { html ->


                GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    val newHtml = replace(html)
                    loadData(newHtml, "text/html", "UTF-8");
                }
            } ?: kotlin.run {
                Log.e("ERROR", "Error loading $url")
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Usage:

```
 val url = "https://example.com"
 webView.loadUrlAndReplace(url) {html->
       html.replace("Original Text","New Text")
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can not.

You have two options, you can get html source code - parse it and try to adjust design in your android app + add functionality by yourself.

Or display website as Webview, but it will be completely useless, because you can only view content of the page and there is no way to change text etc.

In either way you have to do almost everything by yourself. But having and idea already is a good start anyway, wish you luck!